# How to identify if a range contains one substring but not another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My spreadsheet has cells with lists of numbers as strings (representing items in another document) separated by commas. Here are the contents of one cell as an example:

`1.1, 4.1, 5.2, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 7.10, 8.1, 8.2, 8.4, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4,  11.5`

I want to identify if, for example, the substring `1.3` appears in the cell.

Originally, I planned to use `COUNTIF()` with wildcard selectors around the substring I was searching for, like this:

`COUNTIF(range, "*1.3*")`

However, the value `11.3` causes this to return 1.

How can I identify `1.3` without picking up `11.3`?

Some additional notes:

- The first number in each cell is not preceded by a comma and space, so I can’t use that as part of my selector.
- The last number in each cell is not succeeded by a comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to wrap both the range-value and the search-value in your delimiter:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(", 1.3, "; CONCATENATE(", "; range; ", ")))
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't considered that. Great idea. Unless someone else has a really clean solution, that seems like the way to go.